# how to resolve socketClosed Exception

Tags: java, network-programming

I am implementing a simple chat application.
The server must listen to multiple clients, and the server has to send the data entered by one client to all the clients connected to this server.
I have implemented this by the following code. Unexpectedly I am getting the **java.net.SocketException: socket closed** .
Can anybody resolve this exception and tell where i have to modify the code to send the data to all the clients.

**Client.java**

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.util.*;
 class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("172.26.45.132");
        Socket skt = new Socket(addr, 1234);
        PrintWriter out  = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String msg="";
         while (msg!="exit") {
         msg= sc.next();
         out.println(msg);
         System.out.println("from Server"+br.readLine());
}
     br.close();
out.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
  }
 }
 }
```

**Server.java**

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;
   class Server {
 public static ListenClient clients[] = new ListenClient[3];
public static int clientCount = 0;
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
     ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234);
     Socket skt;
     System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
     while(clientCount < 3){
    skt = srvr.accept();
    clients[clientCount] = new ListenClient(skt,clientCount);
    Thread t = new Thread(clients[clientCount]);
    clientCount++;
    t.start();
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
     System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
  }
    }
 }

   class ListenClient extends Server implements Runnable{
Socket sc;
int id;
ListenClient(Socket sc, int id){
    this.sc=sc;
    this.id = id;
}
public void run(){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
        String msg="";
        while((msg=br.readLine())!=null)   
          {   
             PrintWriter clientsOut;
           for(int j = 0 ; j<=clientCount-1; j++){
            clientsOut = new PrintWriter(clients[j].sc.getOutputStream(),true);
            clientsOut.println(msg);
            clientsOut.close();
          }
         }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

SocketClosedException means *you* have closed the socket and then continued to use it. Closing the input or output stream closes the socket, and the other stream. So closing the output inside a loop that is reading the input doesn't make sense.